# Should I buy a new cable modem?

Tags: cable-modem

My cable modem is about five years old, a Linksys BEFCMU10.  Is there any performance advantage to be gained by getting a newer one?  (I'm thinking maybe a Motorola SB6120.)

I'm currently having intermittent internet connection problems, so I was thinking of replacing the modem just as a troubleshooting move, but I'm wondering if there is any advantage to getting a new one aside from that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something we tend to forget is that electronics get worn just like cars and at some point they get worn out.

Now I'm not an expert on cable modems, but generally to electronics, upgrading will typically yield one or more of these:

- decreased power usage
- decreased size
- increased performance

So even if your current modem is not to blame, upgrading is not a bad idea.

Comment: Definitely wouldn't hurt, especially after 5 years, most broadband modems have a service life of about 3 years. Also, Motorola does make some decent modems.